# iPhone tethering turns on personal hotspot

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, wifi, tethering

Is there a setting on my iPhone that would help prevent my MacBook from changing the personal hotspot setting on my iPhone?

I have the personal hotspot turned off on my iPhone. When I tether my iPhone to my MacBook, it does connect, but that action turns on the iPhone hotspot and without any pop ups on the iPhone asking me to allow this.

See the pic below from my MacBook’s Wifi networks, including the iPhone the hotspot Wifi channel (Archimedes Superposition). This happens even though the personal hotspot was off at the beginning on my iPhone. Both devices are on the same Apple ID.

[image]

Comment: It's just showing you that it can be turned on, the Mac didn't change any settings on your phone.  If the phone and the Mac are logged into the same AppleID, the Mac can ask the phone to allow connections.

Comment: Thank you Mark.  Must be new iOS 16 feature.   I know the setting inside personal hotspot / family sharing  to allow this for all in family , and ask permissions first..

Comment: No, it's been that way for years.

Comment: Good to know, I have never seen that on my Mac book WiFi options before, this was the first time.  Why i was wandering.